# The least value of $y$ if $3y \ge 2-5x$ and $x \in [-2,4]$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

If $3y=2-5x$  and  $x\in [-2,4]$, then we have $$ -2\le \frac{2-3y}{5} \le 4 \implies -6 \le  y \le 4 \implies y_{min}=-6, \quad y_{max}=4.$$
The question here is if $3y\ge 2-5x$ and $x\in[-2,4]$, what is the value of $y_{min}$?

Comment: I have to admit that I did not quite understand the relation between the inequality and the restriction. The inequality implies $5x\geq2-3y$. Then, when taking the restriction into account, one can infer $-10\geq2-3y$, hence $3y\geq12$, hence the least value of $y$ is $4$.

Comment: Another way to get this result is by realizing that if $y\ge \frac{2-5x}{3}$ then $y$ will be greater or equal to even the greatest value of the  linear function $\frac{2-5x}{3}$  on $[-2,4]$, which is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write
$$(2-3y)/5\le x \le [-2,4] \implies (2-3y)/5\le -2 \le ~~\text{and}  ~~ (2-3y)/5 \le 4 $$ $$\implies y\ge 4 \quad \text{and} \quad y \ge -6$$
Finally, taking the overlap last two intervals, we get $y \ge 4$.